# Core Data fetching n best results from database

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Say we have an entity called products, and this entity has attribute called quality_level.
Is there a way to fetch (a single fetch) say 50 best results (using quality_level as condition) from a database that has >50 records...
I know that I can set setFetchLimit:50, but that will only return first 50 results not the best ones by quality_level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both NSSortDescriptor and FetchLimit for **limited+best** results:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fileName" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

 }];

[request setSortDescriptors:@[sd]];
[request setFetchLimit:50];
```